# Reasons behind polymorphism related behaviour in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I read this code somewhere

```
class Foo {
    public int a;
    public Foo() {
        a = 3;
    }
    public void addFive() {
        a += 5;
    }
    public int getA() {
        System.out.println("we are here in base class!");
        return  a;
    }
}

public class Polymorphism extends Foo{
   public int a;
   public Poylmorphism() {
       a = 5;
   }
   public void addFive() {
       System.out.println("we are here !" + a);
       a += 5;
   }

   public int getA() {
        System.out.println("we are here in sub class!");
        return  a;
    }

    public static void main(String [] main) {
        Foo f = new Polymorphism();
        f.addFive();
        System.out.println(f.getA()); // SOP 1
        System.out.println(f.a);      // SOP 2
    }
}
```

For SOP1 we get answer 10 and for SOP2 we get answer 3. Reason for this is that you can't override variables whereas you can do so for methods. This happens because type of the reference variable is checked when a variable is accessed and type of the object is checked when a method is accessed. But I am wondering, just why is it that way? Can anyone explain me what is the reason for this behaviour

Comment: Because the Java Language Specification says so?

Comment: c'mon you are almost at 35K, you must be knowing the real cause ;)

Comment: No, I don't.  I did not design Java.  The JLS is the Word of God in that regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reference is of type Foo; it does not know the type of the object it's referring to.

Even with this, inheritance breaks encapsulation; by permitting the instance fields to be overridden too, encapsulation would be broken even more. Maybe in your subclass you are calling a method from the superclass which relates on the state of the instance field a. The superclass' implementation is based on it's own a (it cannot assume a superclass will exist and it will override it) and will have a very chaotic behavior if you change it by overriding it.

Also, instance field inheritance should not be permitted since **instance fields should be made private.**

Answer (score 1):

> This happens because type of the reference variable is checked when a variable is accessed and type of the object is checked when a method is accessed. But I am wondering, just why is it that way? Can anyone explain me what is the reason for this behaviour

It is not a type issue, it is a binding issue.

- The `f.a` expression binds *statically* to the field according to the declared type of the variable `f` because fields are cannot be overridden.  And the reason that they cannot be overridden is that that could break substitutability (for non-private fields) and break methods declared in the supertype that use the field.
- The `f.getA()` call binds *dynamically* to the method in the actual object in order to implement dynamic polymorphism, and in order to prevent callers from breaking abstraction by mistakenly calling a method that had been overridden.

In short, if the binding method was different in either case, the net result would be a less expressive language with problems maintaining abstraction boundaries.

Most, if not all, *statically typed* OO languages work this way.  (If anyone knows of counter examples that are also statically typed, please comment.)